Integrating an External Python Script into a QGIS Project Macro
Is it possible to integrate an external Python script into a QGIS project macro?
I have a relatively large macro that executes various Python commands at the start and end of the project. For better management and overview, I would like to store these commands externally in separate Python files.
How can I achieve this in QGIS? Are there specific methods or best practices for calling external scripts within a project macro?

You can run external .py script with a command like this:
exec(open('filename.py').read())

But I'm not sure if this is a good practice, since the location of the file may change.
In addition, it could lead to the execution of potentially dangerous code if someone modifies the file.

I solved the location problem by combining the project dir with the relative dir using:
project_dir = os.path.dirname(QgsProject.instance().fileName())
os.chdir(project_dir)
